# First non-null value from a list of dicts

Tags: python

Let's suppose that I want to get the first **value** of `key` that is **not** null inside this list of dicts:

```
arr = [
    {
      "key": None,
      "anotherkey": 0
    },
    {
      "another": "ignore"
    },
    {
      "bool": True,
      "key": "this!"
    }
  ]
```

Is there some one-liner to do this? I made it using a for loop.

Comment: small remark: take into account that before ```python3.7```, Dictionaries were orderless and this would therefore not make much sense.

Comment: @CoryKramer You are right, I've misunderstood the question. My bad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop over the inner dictionaries and check for a `key` that isn't `None` using a generator expression within [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> next((d['key'] for d in arr if d.get('key') is not None), None)
'this!'
```

This will return the first value associated with `'key'`, otherwise `None` if no such key/value pairs exist.

Comment: technically, you don't need the `None` in `i.get`

Comment: Didnt knew that syntax for `next` @Tomerikoo - learned something today then :)